# Morse Code - Binary Tree

Tags: java, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, morse-code

How is the Morse Code representation of a letter determined?

"E" = "."
"T" = "-"

Why is it not alphabetic? As in let "A" = ".", "B" = "-", "C" =".-", etc.

I'm trying to develop an algorithm for a traversing Binary Tree filled with these letter.

My main aim is to search for a letter, like "A", but I don't know what conditions to use that determines when to branch to the right or left node.

EDIT

This is what I tried to do. Here I'm trying to keep a track of the path. But when I try it with a leter like "E", it says the root is empty.

```
static boolean treeContains( Node root, String item ) {
     // Return true if item is one of the items in the binary
         // sort tree to which node points.   Return false if not.
     if ( root == null ) {
           // Tree is empty, so it certainly doesn't contain item.
         System.out.print("Is null");
        return false;
     }
     else if ( item.equals(root.element) ) {
           // Yes, the item has been found in the root node.
        return true;
     }
     else if ( item.compareTo(root.element) < 0 ) {
           // If the item occurs, it must be in the left subtree.
           // So, return the result of searching the left subtree.
        res = res.concat(".");
        return treeContains( root.right, item );
     }
     else {
           // If the item occurs, it must be in the right subtree.
           // So, return the result of searching the right subtree.
        res = res.concat("-");
        return treeContains( root.left, item );
     }
  }  // end treeContains()
```

Comment: If you want to know how Morse code assignments came to be, you should talk to Samuel Morse, or look up Morse code in Wikipedia.  My general understanding is that it's based on letter frequency, the short codes are assigned to the most frequently used letters.

Comment: If I remember correctly, the most common letters are written with the least amount of dots and dashes. Take a look at [this image](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/ca/Morse_code_tree3.png) (notice the dots and dashes on the lines) for a binary tree representation.

Comment: Why would you need to use binary tree here, if simple mapping ('letter' => 'code') would suffice, I wonder?

Comment: @raina77ow I have to use a Binary tree.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a Binary Tree with letters in it, then let left be a dot (.) and right be a dash (-).  As you traverse the tree, then you know what the binary code for each letter will is, by keeping track of the path.

EDIT

Looking at your code, you're not traversing the tree properly.  First, I'm not sure what the variable `res` is, but I'm betting it's a static, which is not good coding practice.

Your real problem is that your comparison `item.compareTo(root.element) < 0` is not a valid comparison for this tree.  Instead, you should use a recursive call as your test, `treeContains( root.right, item )`.  Only if this returns true can you then append the dot (.) to your `res` string.  If it returns false, then you can make the recursive call using `root.left` and append a dash (-).

Personally, I would return a string from this method.  The string would be the morse code for the letter so far, or null if the letter is not found.  As you return back from the correct tree traversal, build up the correct string (what you're using for res right now).

Something to test for is that you may have to concat to the front of the string instead of the back of the string to get things to come out correct.

The real usefulness of this tree is in decoding the Morse code, converting a dot-dash string to its correct letter.  This becomes a simple tree traversal.

Comment: Yes, that's what I tried to do but it didn't work. Pls look at my edit.